# libgdx Ontouch only once

Tags: touch, libgdx

When I click my screen I need to execute code only once, but the code is executing a lot of times while the screen is not released. Here is my code:

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched(0)){
        gx = Gdx.input.getX();
        gy = Gdx.input.getY();

        for(int i=1; i<=7; i++){
            d = (int) Math.sqrt(((gx-pomx[i])*(gx-pomx[i])) + ((gy-pomy[i])*(gy-pomy[i])));

            if(d<r){
                sestoagolnik_objekt.setRotation(stepen += 60);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have this code in your `render()` method. This method is called continuously. And of course `Gdx.input.isTouched()` will return `true` as long as you keep the screen touched or the mouse button down.

If you want to track just the first event of "touch down", then you need to implement an `InputProcessor`. See [this link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling) for example code how to do so.

Answer (score 10):

Libgdx has a built-in method for testing if this is the "first" touch event of a press:
[Gdx.input.justTouched()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#justTouched%28%29)